# Beamer - How to change section and subsection text color

Tags: beamer, color, section-titles

I would like to have a yellow text instead of a white one for the section and subsection text. Using `\setbeamercolor{section}{fg =yellow}` doesn't change those colours

```
\documentclass[t,compress,squeeze,smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             %linux
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usetheme[shadow]{Berlin}
\setbeamercolor{section }{fg =yellow}
\setbeamercolor{subsection }{fg =yellow}


\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\begin{frame}
Blablabla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour of the (sub)section in the headline via `(sub)section in head/foot`:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,squeeze,smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             %linux
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usetheme[shadow]{Berlin}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=yellow}


\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\begin{frame}
Blablabla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Was just wondering: are the blanks inside the { } relevant?

Comment: @MS-SPO Spaces are part of the colour name, so they are relevant. For the key-values, they aren't necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @Nelou You're welcome!